# nvcc fatal : Unknown option 'fmad'

Tags: cuda

compiling John the Ripper with cuda on Ubuntu 12.04 x86

nvcc -c -Xptxas -v -fmad=true -arch sm_10 cuda_common.cu -o ../cuda_common.o
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'fmad'
make[1]: *** [cuda_common.o] Error 255
make: *** [linux-x86-cuda] Error 2

Comment: Which CUDA version are you using?  (`nvcc --version`)

Comment: It's likely that you're seeing this particular error because your CUDA version is 4.0 or prior.  The `fmad` option for `nvcc` was [introduced with cuda 4.1](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#new-features-in-cuda-release-4-1).

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `fmad` option or increasing your compute capability target.

`-fmad=true` is not a valid option for your targeted compute capability (1.0). `fmad` (fused multiply add) became available on compute capability 2.0 (Fermi).

From the `nvcc` help:

> --fmad=true and --fmad=false enables and disables the contraction respectively. This switch is supported only when the --gpu-architecture option is set withcompute_20, sm_20, or higher. For other architecture classes, the contraction is always enabled.

Comment: Actually, the (nvcc 4.1 or newer) compiler will accept `-fmad=true` even when arch is sm_10.  The `false` setting is only supported on sm_20 or higher.  The `true` setting is the default and only acceptable option for `sm_10`, so if you specify `true`, the compiler will accept it without throwing an error, even if you specify arch of sm_10.